# Using symbols read by scanf() as C operators

Tags: c, math, input

I want to read a symbol in from `scanf()` and then get C to use it for what it is. My current (relevant) piece of code looks like:

```
float a;     /* First Number */
char  sym;   /* Symbol (i.e. +, -, /, *) */
float b;     /* Second number.... */

puts("Please type your equation");
printf("$: ");

scanf("%f %c %f", &a, &sym, &b);
```

So if the user were to type (at the `$:` prompt) `5 + 10` then the program should proceed to evaluate `5 + 10` but I know I can't expect C to do this (not without working some magic first :) because '+' is just an ANSI character code, so what I'm asking is:

**How do I get C to literally take the variable `sym` for what we (as people) take it as (a plus `+`) and then use that to solve the equation as if the variables had hard-coded values?**

<kbd>EDIT</kbd>
I now understand that it may be impossible (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850924/c-using-the-return-value-of-scanf-literally#comment55466360_33850924) by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)), so any workarounds would be great!

*Just as a side-note: I know I can use*

```
....
add(int a, int b)
{
        return (1 + b);
}
....
if (sym == '+') {
        add(a, b);
}
```

and so on, but when the I get to including more then just `a` and `b` (e.g. `a`, `sym`, `b`, `sym2`, `c`) and the user has more than a single type of operator (e.g. `2 + 4 - 6`) this becomes tedious and time consuming.

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to write a parser.

Comment: You can't execute C code at runtime. You'd have to write a parser to parse the equations and execute them, which is a nontrivial task.

Comment: Why are you doing this exactly? Is there a shortage of calculator programs?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz hahahaha no, there are enough calculator programs, but what better way to learn then program my own?

Comment: @Ankush Then I'm kind of puzzled why you would ask how *not* to write  calculator program.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do that.  C is a compiled language (so is C++) and you cannot just execute a string as if it is C code at run time.  The instructions are generated when the code is compiled.  Other languages like Python which are interpreted support this (such as the `eval` function in Python).  Using the if statements is probably the most efficient approach.

Also like [Jiang Jie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3069208/jiang-jie) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850953) I would look into [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).  This involves using a stack to evaluate the mathematical expressions and can handle complex expressions.

You will also probably need to look into converting infix expressions (e.g. `1 + 2`) into postfix expressions (`1 2 +`).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to learn C by interpreting it, then as you'll need a tokenizer, a parser and an expression tree evaluator. I know there are the old classics: LEX and YACC, but I'm pretty sure there are newer tokenizers and parser generators. You can google for "C parser generator". There's even a Wikipedia article comparing a bunch of them.

But I will say that writing a C interpreter is not the best way to learn C. Learning to write simpler programs is highly recommended. I suggest finding a tutorial site or getting a book. There are lots of both.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **Reverse Polish Notation**, let the user input a regular math expression, then you need to transform it into an RPN expression, then calculate.

Comment: Do you know of any function, in say `math.h`, or will I have to create my own?

Comment: No, you have to write your own, I think you can find its implementation in any algorithm books.

Comment: Whether you use *RPN* or a *standard equation* your job is the same. Read the input, parse the numbers and the operators, determine what operators were given (e.g. `+`, `-`, `*`, etc.), and compute the result accordingly. Nothing more, nothing less. There are probably no less than 20 examples on StackOverflow.