# how to avoid the '+''-' vanshing but no-sense?

Tags: c, input

```
unsigned u;
int i = scanf("%u",&u);
int c = getchar();
printf("%d is %u%c",i,u,c);//unsigned still has a type like orignal type
return 0;
```

input

```
+
```

output

```
0 is 4198579'\n'
```

'\n' is what I add.
So how to avoid the '+''-' vanshing but no-sense?
If I want to achieve a complex number type,how to class "+i","-i" and "-888"?
scanf("%d") ,if it's false,'+''-' have been taking out,-i couldn't be represented correctly.

Comment: If `i < 1`, do not use `u`.  It is _undefined behavior_ UB.

Comment: You should read your input as string and parse it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = scanf("%u",&u);
```

You have to initialize `u` with some values or at least provide some values to `scanf`. If you don't supply input during scanf then `u` is a uninitialized local variable with a garbage value. Also use `fgets` instead of scanf which is considered more safe.

```
0 is 4198579'\n'
```

Please read,

> [Using symbols read by scanf() as C operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850924/using-symbols-read-by-scanf-as-c-operators)

Even getchar() doesn't help. You need to write your own parser for this.

Or if you just want signs to be printed try to use ASCIIs,

```
#define PLUSSIGN 43


unsigned int u = PLUSSIGN;
printf("%d is %u%c",i,u,c);
```

Other ways include using enumerated type to define signs with ASCII values. This helps if you want to programmatically use a sign depending on some inputs,
or you could just use them as a string(the easiest way) in a `switch` statement. Select any of the methods depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sincerely! I guess I'm too eager to find a simple way.